# Can R normalizePath() be forced to not truncate long paths?

Tags: r

I have a long file path (year/month/day/partition directory style where I'm only interested in some partitions - so wildcards don't work well). The read function I'm using calls `normalizePaths` internally. However, as shown in the simplified example below, the only effect of `normalizePaths` (given that I am using absolute paths to begin with) is to truncate my path at 4095 characters. This makes it an invalid path and causes my read operation to fail.

```
path <- paste0(rep("/pretend/path", times=400), collapse="/")
nchar(path)
# [1] 5599
nchar(normalizePath(path, mustWork = FALSE))
# [1] 4095
substr(path, 1, 4095) == normalizePath(path, mustWork = FALSE)
# [1] TRUE
```

I am using R v3.4.1.

Why does `normalizePaths` truncate at all? Is there a way to change this behavior (e.g., using an `options()` setting)?

---

Update adding `sessionInfo`

```
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6 (Santiago)

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so
LAPACK: /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRlapack.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.1
```

Comment: it would depend on stuff... what does `sessionInfo()` show?

Comment: The [source code](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/include/Defn.h#L258-L262) suggests linux allows up to 4192, though it's not surprising to me it is a little below this (perhaps object metadata, I don't know). Other OSes are considerably lower. This is relatively low-level, I do not know if/how you would be able to change this short of recompiling R (perhaps not what you want to attempt).